# jQuery: Add form to page 10 seconds after page load

Tags: jquery, load

Please help me this problem. I research more but I can't resolve issue.
I have code 1:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
function needloadafterloadpage(){
    $form = $('<form method="get" action="" id="form-cmtxxx"></form>');
    $form.html('<textarea name="add_comment_text" title="Write a comment..." content="Write a comment..." placeholder="Write a comment..." class="textInput mentionsTextarea uiTextareaAutogrow uiTextareaNoResize UFIAddCommentInput DOMControl_placeholder" id="scriptBox26" />');
    $('#wrappercontentpost').html($form);
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="wrappercontentpost"></div>
<script>    
    $('textarea').on('keydown',function(e){
        alert("abc");
    });
</script>
<script>
needloadafterloadpage();
</script>
</body>
```

Code jquery don't working in this case. I want to append form to div after 10s. Do you have any way to reload Jquery.
Thanks for your support very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation since when the event registration script is executed the textarea element does not exists in the dom

Then use `setTimeout` to append the form after 10 seconds

so overall

```
function needloadafterloadpage() {
    $form = $('<form method="get" action="" id="form-cmtxxx"></form>');
    $form.append('<textarea name="add_comment_text" title="Write a comment..." content="Write a comment..." placeholder="Write a comment..." class="textInput mentionsTextarea uiTextareaAutogrow uiTextareaNoResize UFIAddCommentInput DOMControl_placeholder" id="scriptBox26" />');
    $('#wrappercontentpost').append($form);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#wrappercontentpost').on('keydown', 'textarea', function (e) {
        console.log("abc");
    });
})
setTimeout(needloadafterloadpage, 10000)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QbF6W/)

Comment: The delegated event handler wouldn't be needed if the `.on()` was moved into the `needloadafterloadpage()` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes... of course... I just kept the design as the OP did

Comment: Fair enough. Though you didn't need to add the document ready handler given that the script block with that code appears after the `#wrappercontentpost` element. In any case +1 since this is the only answer (so far) to both fix the event handler and introduce the 10 second delay.

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right... I think it just came as the normal practice

Answer (score 0):

change the part of code:

```
<script>    
    $('textarea').on('keydown',function(e){
        alert("abc");
    });
</script>
```

with one:

```
<script>    
    $(function() {
       $('textarea').on('keydown',function(e){
          alert("abc");
       });
   });
</script>
```

Explanation: you didn't initialize jquery library with `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: _"you didn't initialize jquery plugin"_ - What plugin? Also a document ready handler doesn't initialise jQuery: jQuery doesn't require initialisation (unless you count including jquery.js as initialisation).

Comment: OK. But jQuery doesn't need to be initialised.

Comment: Then how to know about `$` symbol with associated methods and properties ? Look over Arun's answer and you'll see `jQuery(function ($) {` ... which it initialize jquery library.

Comment: But you didn't do that, you just used `$` everywhere. Anyway, that's not initialising jQuery either, it's just setting up an alias with a local variable. Again, _you don't need a document ready handler to make jQuery work,_ as you can see here: http://jsbin.com/UFekOyO/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = '<form method="get" action="" id="form-cmtxxx"><textarea name="add_comment_text" title="Write a comment..." content="Write a comment..." placeholder="Write a comment..." class="textInput mentionsTextarea uiTextareaAutogrow uiTextareaNoResize UFIAddCommentInput DOMControl_placeholder" id="scriptBox26" /></form>';
window.setTimeout(function(){$('#wrappercontentpost').html(form);}, 10000);
});
```

will make the form appear after 10 seconds, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
function addForm() {
    var form = '<form method="get" action="" id="form-cmtxxx"><textarea name="add_comment_text" title="Write a comment..." content="Write a comment..." placeholder="Write a comment..." class="textInput mentionsTextarea uiTextareaAutogrow uiTextareaNoResize UFIAddCommentInput DOMControl_placeholder" id="scriptBox26" /></form>';
    $('#wrappercontentpost').html(form);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        addForm();
    },10000);
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="wrappercontentpost"></div>
</body>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WrBrx/